# How do you remove the white box behind a chart series label?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there is a way to remove the white box around the series label in a chart. I am using the built in chart from the toolbox in Visual Studio 2010. This is the last part I need to finish the appearance of the chart to make it look the way I want. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the white box you are describing, but to change the properties of that section of the chart, click it in the designer, go over to the Properties window on the right, and scroll down to Legends.

Once there, hit the `[...]` button next to it, and that will bring up the set of all of the legends.  Select the legend you want, and adjust the `BorderColor` property to the background color.  I didn't see a means by which you could turn the border off, nor does it seem like you can set the width of the border to 0.

These can also be set programmatically, like `Chart1.Legends(0).BorderColor = Color.White`